# In yarn v3, how can we get list of only prod dependencies

Tags: package.json, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v3

I need to get a list of only prod dependencies with yarn 3. Could not find any option in official documentation for listing only prod or devDependencies.

Corresponding npm command is `npm list --omit=dev`

The available [command to get list](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/info) of all the dependencies is: `yarn info --recursive`

Is there a workaround to get only prod dependencies list with yarn v3?